# SAS/SQL - Getting date field table A that greater or equal to the date field from table B, and get the maximum date from table B

Tags: sql, sas

i would like to achieve the following:
For each customer (custID) in table A, get the trade_date and find the maximum create date that is smaller or equal to trade_date (based on customer as matching field). Get the rating for the particular maximum create date record and join back to table A (which is desired Table C)

Trade_Table A:

```
CustID | Trade_date | Trade_ID
12345  | 30/7/2018  |  4axd
12345  | 30/7/2018  |  
12345  | 31/7/2018  |  5FETF
12345  | 05/9/2018  |  fst43d
12366  | 01/8/2018  |  g3fgg
12377  | 01/9/2018  |  dfd45
```

Risk_Rating_Table B:

```
CustID | Create_date | Rating
12345  | 29/7/2018   |  2
12345  | 30/7/2018   |  3
12345  | 31/7/2018   |  4
12345  | 01/9/2018   |  1
12366  | 30/7/2018   |  1
12377  | 31/9/2018   |  5
```

Final_Table C:

```
CustID | Trade_date | Trade_ID | Rating
12345  | 30/7/2018  |  4axd    | 3
12345  | 30/7/2018  |          | 3
12345  | 31/7/2018  |  5FETF   | 4
12345  | 05/9/2018  |  fst43d  | 1
12366  | 01/8/2018  |  g3fgg   | 1
12377  | 01/9/2018  |  dfd45   |
```

i tried many ways, which this is one, but i got a more than 1 row returned error. This is more complex than i thought it will be.

```
proc sql;
create Final_Table C as select 
A.*, 
(select max(B.Create_date) FROM Risk_Rating_Table B where A.trade_date >=  B.Create_date
group by B.CustID 
)  as Rating
from
Trade_Table A 
;
QUIT;
```

Comment: . . This is probably easier using a data step with `retain` than using `proc sql`.  If you are using an external database, then it probably supports `lag()`, which is the right SQL method.

Comment: thanks for the assistance. for some reasons i needed to use proc sql. i suppose lag() is not supported in sas. anyways, i was figuring out to do a group by custid, trade_date, condition, where condition is a user defined field in SELECT where condition = 1 if trade_date >= create_date, and 0 otherwise. After that, i will do a max create_date based on having max(condition) = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SQL Guru @Gordon Linoff said that it would be quiet difficult to do this in PROC SQL, I think it is better to use some datastep or hash technique. I am able to emulate your results and not sure how efficient it is. I have transposed data and used array to avoid many to many joins.

```
 /* create test data*/
  data Trade_Table;
  infile datalines missover;
 input CustID  Trade_date:ddmmyy10.  Trade_ID $;
  format Trade_date:ddmmyy10.;
 datalines;
 12345   30/7/2018    4axd
 12345   30/7/2018    
 12345   31/7/2018    5FETF
 12345   05/9/2018    fst43d
 12366   01/8/2018    g3fgg
 12377   01/9/2018    dfd45
  ;

 /* second test data */     
 data Risk_Rating_Table ;
 input CustID  Create_date:ddmmyy10.  Rating;
 format Create_date ddmmyy10.;
 datalines;
 12345   29/7/2018     2
 12345   30/7/2018     3
 12345   31/7/2018     4
 12366   30/7/2018     1
 12377   30/9/2018     5
  ;

 /* tranpose the data so the date comes in rows and then it is easy to compare*/
  proc transpose data = Risk_Rating_Table out =one(drop =_name_);
   by custid ;
   var create_date;
   run;

   /* merge the master table with tranposed table and may to have sort data*/
   data have1;
   merge Trade_Table one;
   by custid;
    run;

    /* compare ge columns in a array*/
    data have2;
    set have1;
    array col(*) col1-col3;
    do i=1 to 3 while(col{i} le Trade_date);
   new=col{i};
     end;
    format new ddmmyy10.;
     /* try out more examples may for this part*/
     if new = . then new= max(of col:);
     drop col: i;
    run;

    /* get back required columns */
      proc sql;
       create table want as
     select a.CustID ,Trade_date , Trade_ID , case  
        when a.custid = b.custid and trade_date ge create_date
         then b.rating
         else .
         end as rating
    from have2 a
  left join
  Risk_Rating_Table b
   on a.custid = b.custid
   and create_date =new;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT Tmp.CustID ,Tmp.Trade_date,Tmp.Trade_ID,Tmp.Create_date,B.Rating 
FROM (    SELECT A.CustID ,A.Trade_date, A.Trade_ID, MAX(B.Create_date) as Create_date
    FROM TableA A
    JOIN TableB B ON A.CustID = B.CustID 
    WHERE A.Trade_date >=B.Create_date
    GROUP BY A.CustID ,A.Trade_date, A.Trade_ID
)Tmp
JOIN TableB B ON Tmp.CustID = B.CustID AND Tmp.Create_date = B.Create_date
```

Comment: unfortunately i don't think this works:  the "WHERE A.XX  >= B.XX" is processed before group by , and it processes record by record

Answer (score 0):

i managed to solve this per below- comments welcome.

```
    proc sql;
create table tmp_dcpbase as SELECT 
A.custid ,A.Trade_date, 
CASE
    WHEN  A.Trade_date >=B.CREATE_DATE is not null  THEN 1
    ELSE  0
END as CONSIDER ,
PUT(max(B.CREATE_DATE), datetime16. ) AS RPQCr8DTForm,
max(B.CREATE_DATE) as RPQCr8DT
FROM Trade_Table as a inner join RISK_RATING_Table as b
ON (a.custID = b.custID ) 
GROUP BY A.custID , A.trade_date,CONSIDER 
having MAX(CONSIDER) = 1
;
quit;

proc sql;
create table target_C as select 
D.custID , D.Trade_date,D.Trade_id, tmp2.RPQCr8DTForm , TMP2.Rating from
(
SELECT A.*, b.Rating
FROM 
tmp_dcpbase A
INNER JOIN RISK_RATING_Table  b ON (a.custID = b.custID AND a.RPQCr8DT = b.CREATE_DATE)
) TMP2 right join trade_table D ON (TMP2.custID =  D.custID AND TMP2.trade_date = d.trade_date)
;
quit;
```